# How do I return the intersection of two lists including duplicates in mathematica?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

How do I find the intersection of two lists including duplicates in mathematica?

So, If I have this:

```
list1 = {1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 10, 11, 11};
list2 = {1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 11, 11, 13, 14};
```

I'd want it to return this:

```
IntersectionIncludingDuplicates[list1, list2] = {1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 11, 11}
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
Catenate@KeyValueMap[ConstantArray]@
  MapThread[Min, KeyIntersection[Counts /@ {list1, list2}]]
```

Breaking it down:

- Count how many times each element occurs in each list (`Counts`)
- Retain only those elements which occur in both (`KeyIntersection`)
- Take the smaller number of occurrences (`MapThread`, `Min`) and replicate the given element that many times (`ConstantArray`)

Answer (score 0):

Edit : fixed and tested..

you might use regular `Intersection` , then `Count` , something like

```
ConstantArray[#, Min[Count[list1, #], Count[list2, #]]] & /@ 
  Intersection[list1, list2] // Flatten
```

> {1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 11, 11}

in functional form generalised to take an arbitrary number of lists:

```
IntersectionIncludingDuplicates[lists__List] := 
 ConstantArray[#, 
     Function[{v}, Min @@ (Count[#, v] & /@ {lists})]@#] & /@
   Intersection[lists] // Flatten
IntersectionIncludingDuplicates[list1, list2]
```

> > {1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 11, 11}

Answer (score 0):

Simple code to understand.  Assumes input lists are sorted.

```
list1 = {1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 10, 11, 11};
list2 = {1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 11, 11, 13, 14};

IntersectionIncludingDuplicates[list1_, list2_] := Module[

  {out = {}, i = j = 1},

  While[i <= Length[list1] && j <= Length[list2],
   If[list1[[i]] == list2[[j]],
    AppendTo[out, list1[[i]]];
    i++; j++,
    If[list1[[i]] < list2[[j]], i++, j++]]];

  out]

IntersectionIncludingDuplicates[list1, list2]
```

> {1, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 11, 11}